# Static members going missing after TSC

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have a class containing global values that I am declaring as static in typescript.

It looks like this:

```
export default class Globals {
    // All members should be public static - no instantiation required
    public static GraphAPIToken: null
    public static APP_ID: "appidstringhere"
    public static APP_SECRET: "thisisasecret"
    public static TOKEN_ENDPOINT: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/aaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    public static MS_GRAPH_SCOPE: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
}
```

After compilation to js using TSC (Typescript 3.7.3) it results in the following:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var Globals = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Globals() {
    }
    return Globals;
}());
exports["default"] = Globals;
```

My question is, what happened to my members!?

Any ideas welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you're declaring the type of your static variables here as the intended values of your static variables. For example:

`public static APP_ID: "appidstringhere"`

which says that `APP_ID` is of type `"appidstringhere"`, when you should be saying:

`public static APP_ID: string = "appidstringhere"`

which says that `APP_ID` is of type `string`, and has value `"appidstringhere"`.

Comment: The type can be inferred from the initializer, so `: string` is optional here.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually assigning your members, you're defining them as undefined variables with types. Use `=` instead of `:`.

```js
export default class Globals {
    // All members should be public static - no instantiation required
    public static GraphAPIToken = null;
    public static APP_ID = "appidstringhere";
    public static APP_SECRET = "thisisasecret";
    public static TOKEN_ENDPOINT = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/aaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    public static MS_GRAPH_SCOPE = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
}
```

Additional context: TypeScript allows for string and integer constants to work as types, such that a parameter that accepts `left` and `right` would throw a compile-time error if you pass in a string that isn't one of those two values. Unlike an object definition, such as `{foo: "bar"}`, you have defined a `class`, and class fields in TypeScript use `:` to define types and `=` to define values.

I think it's interesting that TypeScript doesn't complain that don't supposedly accept `undefined`, but that's a separate question.